# Can I send slack alert message through bot using python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, slack, slack-api

I want to alert everyone on `Slack App`, which I can do manually by sending `@here` in the channel.
But I want to send it using my bot.

So, I tried this:

```
import numpy as np
import requests

data = {
    'token': token,
    'channel': channel,    
    'as_user': True,
    'text': "<@here>"
}

requests.post(url='https://slack.com/api/chat.postMessage', data=data)
```

But it send just a usual message, not an alert message.

How can I send an alert message using my bot?